# Cannot find the create package menu in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have a trouble to add a package under one of the flavor folder in Android Studio: after I right click on the java folder and I could not see the 'Package' or 'Java Classes' options there!

I did exactly the same for another flavor and it was fine.. Now I am stuck here, without knowing if it is a bug in AS or I did anything there. Anyone help me please!

(I googled it and did not solve it with what I have found so far)

[image]

=======**EDIT**========

I close the project and create a brand new empty project, now even in the main folder I cannot find the 'Java Classes' or 'Package' when I right click on the java folder I added.

**However**, if I just create the folders of the package under java with a class there, and do a build, it will finally recognize that and make java blue color and then I am able to see the menus if I right click the blue java folder.

So it sounds like some bug in AS.

Comment: I had a same problem as this. Seems like on changing the build Flavor enables the "new package" option. Like for demo flavor, the option will available to demo folder not for other flavor folders.

Comment: @RajatSaxena, that's true. I also found this and forgot to update this post. Thank you

Comment: so how do i add package to my flavour2 java folder.

Answer (score 12):

It might just be the build flavor you are currently selected correctly to enable that flavor.

If we have two build flavor let's say free and pro. If pro is selected is current build flavor. The flavor free will not be shown as java package in blue color as you mentioned, it will be shown as directory structure. Hence change the build variant and make it workable.

Not sure if you faced the same issue, but sharing it for reference of others who might face this issue as i faced now.

Answer (score 5):

Package option is available only for selected flavor. switch to desired flavor and IDE will refer that source directory and will convert it to package and directories from other flavors will be listed as normal directories tree structure.

Answer (score 5):

Control click (mac), or right click the /java directory and select Mark Directory As -> Source Root. You should then be able to right click the /java directory and select -> New -> Package. Your java directory will also appear blue.

Answer (score 5):

I found this Solution.

File > Project Structure > Select the lib folder > Click on Sources > Apply and Okay

Now you can see the new package option by right clicking the lib folder, the new package option will be shown.

Step1

[image: Step1]

Step2

[image: Step2]

Step3

[image: Step3]

Answer (score 1):

Solution. File- Project Structure- Modules- Right click on lib - Select  Sources.
then the option "Package" will appear on your list.