# package directory on android studio flutter

Tags: android, flutter

In a Flutter tutorial video
In Android Studio, you can right-click on the lib to create a package directory, but this option does not exist for me, can anyone help me why this option does not exist for me?

(Please check the image)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gpgx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click -> New -> Package

[image]

Comment: I added an image to the post and you can see that there is no such option

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67799966) method